# Trying to run AfterMethod with assertion

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a lot of Test methods in my testing class. My goal is to have the ability to use assertion twice: the first time in each Test and the second time in each AfterMethod test.

Here is an example of my code:

```
 @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true )
public void reportTestFail() {

   String a = getAllParameters().get("A");
   if (a.contains("1")) {
       asserter.fail("1 is found in parameters");
   }
   else {
       asserter.assertTrue(true,"Test passed");
   }
}
```

Why do I always get failed configuration at the end of each test?

Can't I assert outside of the Test methods?

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: I am trying to use the same asserter Object twice: in the original test and the @AfterMethod that comes after it.

Comment: Though a stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, but the stacktrace tells reveals nothing. Can I run a test using 2 unique methods? That's is what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you should utilize TestNG [IInvokedMethodListener2](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener2.html) or `IInvokedMethodListener` (for TestNG release 7+) and do additional validation in `afterInvocation`. In implementation of this method you should write your assertions in `try-catch` block and in catch block you should set testMethod status to fail and set exception.   For example:

```java
public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult, ITestContext context){
 try{
  //perform addition validations
 }catch(Exception e){
   //assertion failed
   //update testResult to fail
 }
}
```

To modify result of testcase refer code in [qaf](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/blob/d58b1d1ca01b2df1a916bcd6d555df4f51a13b12/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/testng/pro/QAFTestNGListener.java#L306).

Comment: IInvokedMethodListener2 interface is deprecated. What else may I do?

Comment: use `IInvokedMethodListener` instead. >InvokedMethodListener2 @deprecated As of release 7.0.0, replaced by {@link org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener}